Is there any legal justification for a civilian to carry a gun in New Caledonia?
The is currently civil unrest in the French Island of New Caledonia.  In a news segment a "business man" admits to carrying a gun  "all the time to handle any situation".
My understanding is that French gun laws are quite strict, and quite strictly enforced. According to wikipedia "No civilian may carry any weapons in a public place".  If someone made such an admission on international TV during unrest in say Paris I would expect them to bet getting a call from the police.  What is the legal situation in New Caledonia?

It would if this was Paris
